# PyQt Frame for BoxLayout

Tags: pyqt5, qvboxlayout

I've now been stucked more than 2 hours, trying to put a frame/border around my Boxlayout.

This is main minimal Main.py

```
from PyQt5 import QtGui
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
import circle


class fenster(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.top = 100
        self.left = 100
        self.width = 900
        self.height = 1200

        self.initMe()

    def DisplayMainWindowBox(self):

        maingrahpic = QVBoxLayout()

        topgraphicbox = QFormLayout()
        circle1 = circle.circle()
        topgraphicbox.addWidget(circle1)

        BottomGraphicBox = QFormLayout()
        circle2 = circle.circle()
        BottomGraphicBox.addWidget(circle2)

        maingrahpic.addLayout(topgraphicbox)
        maingrahpic.addLayout(BottomGraphicBox)

        return (maingrahpic)

    def initMe(self):

        # define boxes for boxLayout
        horizontalmainbox = QHBoxLayout()

        rbtnrow = QVBoxLayout()
        rlabelrow = QVBoxLayout()

        lbtnrow = QVBoxLayout()
        llabelrow = QVBoxLayout()

        bottombtnrow = QHBoxLayout()
        bottomlabelrow = QHBoxLayout()

        maingraphicbox = self.DisplayMainWindowBox()

        middlebox = QHBoxLayout()
        middlebox.addLayout(llabelrow)
        middlebox.addLayout(maingraphicbox)
        middlebox.addLayout(rlabelrow)

        mainmiddlebox = QVBoxLayout()
        displayvbox = QVBoxLayout()

        frame = QFrame()
        frame.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)
        frame.setStyleSheet("background-color: blue")
        frame.setLineWidth(3)

        displayvbox.addWidget(frame)
        displayvbox.addLayout(middlebox)
        displayvbox.addLayout(bottomlabelrow)

        mainmiddlebox.addLayout(displayvbox)
        mainmiddlebox.addLayout(bottombtnrow)

        horizontalmainbox.addLayout(lbtnrow)
        horizontalmainbox.addLayout(mainmiddlebox)
        horizontalmainbox.addLayout(rbtnrow)

        topbox = QHBoxLayout()
        toprightside = QHBoxLayout()
        toprightside.addStretch(1)
        topleftside = QVBoxLayout()
        topbox.addLayout(toprightside)
        topbox.addLayout(topleftside)

        finalbox = QVBoxLayout()

        finalbox.addLayout(topbox)
        finalbox.addLayout(horizontalmainbox)


        self.setLayout(finalbox)

        self.setGeometry(self.top, self.left, self.width, self.height)
        self.setWindowTitle("ACDI Simulator")
        self.show()

        self.setStyleSheet("background : black;")


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
app.setStyle("fuison")
w = fenster()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

To make the programm code work u need circle.py

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
import sys


class circle(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        timer = QTimer(self)

        timer.timeout.connect(self.update)

        timer.start(500)

        self.setWindowTitle('Circle')

        self.setGeometry(200, 200, 300, 300)

        self.setStyleSheet("background : black;")

        self.rPointer = QtGui.QPolygon([QPoint(0, 0),
                                        QPoint(-10, -90),
                                        QPoint(10, -90)])

        self.sPointer = QtGui.QPolygon([QPoint(0, 0),
                                        QPoint(-10, -90),
                                        QPoint(10, -90)])

        self.bColor = Qt.white

        self.GreenCol = Qt.green

        self.sColor = Qt.red

        self.tik = 0

    def paintEvent(self, event):

        rec = min(self.width(), self.height())

        self.tik = self.tik + 1
        self.tik = self.tik % 360

        painter = QPainter(self)

        def drawPointer(color, rotation, pointer):

            painter.setBrush(QBrush(color))

            painter.save()

            painter.rotate(rotation)

            painter.drawConvexPolygon(pointer)

            painter.restore()

        painter.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)

        painter.translate(self.width() / 2, self.height() / 2)

        painter.scale(rec / 200, rec / 200)

        painter.setPen(QtCore.Qt.NoPen)

        drawPointer(self.GreenCol, (self.tik), self.rPointer)

        drawPointer(self.sColor, 90, self.sPointer)

        painter.setPen(QPen(self.bColor, 1, Qt.SolidLine))

        painter.setBrush(QBrush(QtCore.Qt.NoBrush))

        painter.drawEllipse(-92, -92, 184, 184)

        for i in range(0, 90):

            if (i % 5) == 0:
                painter.drawLine(87, 0, 97, 0)

            painter.rotate(9)

        painter.end()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    win = circle()
    win.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Since i am clearly not able to tell what i want here a picture:
[image: Since i am clearly not able to tell what i want here a picture]

I want the a frame around the Displayvbox. The Displayvbox contains some labels and the two circles. How is it possible to make this frame. I really don't get this....

Comment: Please provide a [mre], since the code you're providing is completely insufficient to help you, as it's missing important parts and refers to objects we don't know anything about (for instance, what's inside `FinalBox` and where did you add the DisplayVBox` layout).

Comment: Is this Better?

Comment: Sorry, but no, your example is not minimal *nor* reproducible: it should *at least* be one of those two, in your case it's very extended, and understanding it just by reading is almost impossible (also considering that you're naming variables starting with uppercase letters, which makes it even more difficult to read). Please read the above link, we *must* be able to copy, paste and run your code possibly without any substantial modification, which means that blocks of code related to the same file and/or class should not be splitted by explanatory text (you can use comments for that)

Comment: please avoid unnecessary bad language. Also, the lowercase convention is only for variables and functions, classes and constants *do* begin with uppercase letters. Read more on the official [Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding what you're trying to achieve: is the problem that QFrame you're adding? Because that frame is completely empty, so it doesn't get shown. If you want a frame "around" other widgets, you should put those widget in a layout set for *that* frame.

Comment: In my Main Code i want to make a frame aound 4 diffrent Boxes.
1.DisplayMainWindowBox
2.bottomlabelrow
3.rlabelrow
4.llabelrow

But before i want them in different Boxes so my Layout goes with it. I put rlabelrow/llabelrow left and right to the rlabelrow. The Box resulting from that will be merged together with the bottomlabelrow. Then i want a frame aournd this Box, so all my items are at the right place and will be in a frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A QFrame is a container widget, which is a widget intended only as a way to "group" other widgets.

If you want to show widgets inside a frame, you cannot just add the frame to the layout *and* add those widgets to the same layout: you need to set a layout for the frame, add the widgets to *that* layout, and then add the frame to the "main" layout.

In your case, you can create the frame in `DisplayMainWindowBox` and directly return that instead of the layout:

```py
    def DisplayMainWindowBox(self):

        frame = QFrame()
        frame.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)
        frame.setStyleSheet("background-color: blue")
        frame.setLineWidth(3)

        # directly install the layout on the frame
        maingrahpic = QVBoxLayout(frame)
        # which is the shorthand version of: 
        # maingrahpic = QVBoxLayout(frame)
        # frame.setLayout(maingrahpic)

        topgraphicbox = QFormLayout()
        circle1 = circle()
        topgraphicbox.addWidget(circle1)

        BottomGraphicBox = QFormLayout()
        circle2 = circle()
        BottomGraphicBox.addWidget(circle2)

        maingrahpic.addLayout(topgraphicbox)
        maingrahpic.addLayout(BottomGraphicBox)

        # return the frame, not the layout
        return frame

    def initMe(self):
        # ...
        maingraphicbox = self.DisplayMainWindowBox()

        middlebox = QHBoxLayout()
        middlebox.addLayout(llabelrow)
        middlebox.addWidget(maingraphicbox)
        middlebox.addLayout(rlabelrow)
        # ...
```

I suggest you to read more about [layout management](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html) and also do some experimenting by [using them in Qt designer](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-layouts.html) so that you can better understand how layout management works under Qt.
Also consider that [`width()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#width-prop) and [`height()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#height-prop) are existing attributes of all QWidget classes, so you should not overwrite them with custom variables, as doing it would make access to those properties more difficult.

Finally, your circle subclass should probably inherit from QWidget and not QMainWindow (which is normally intended to be used as a top level window, not as a custom widget that is going to be added to a parent).

Comment: Only needed a hour + the rest of my nerves to add this to my gui, thanks.